# Unexpected conversion error while converting value [BigNumber] to a BigNumber

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am getting the field X from a lookup and trying to Load into a table using Insert/Update. But I get an error saying  "Unexpected conversion error while converting value [BigNumber] to a BigNumber"
I have even used select values and gave type with Big Number and still doesn't work. Any Suggestions?

```
Insert / update.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Error in step, asking everyone to stop because of:
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - offending row : [visitGroupRefnum BigNumber], [visitRefnum BigNumber], [questionRefnum BigNumber], [answerid Integer(9)]
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - Error setting value #3 [BigNumber] on prepared statement
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [questionRefnum BigNumber] to a BigNumber
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.setValues(Database.java:1076)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.insertupdate.InsertUpdate.lookupValues(InsertUpdate.java:83)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.insertupdate.InsertUpdate.processRow(InsertUpdate.java:299)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - Error setting value #3 [BigNumber] on prepared statement
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [questionRefnum BigNumber] to a BigNumber
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.setPreparedStatementValue(ValueMetaBase.java:5473)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.setValue(Database.java:1058)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.setValues(Database.java:1074)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   ... 4 more
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleValueException: 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [questionRefnum BigNumber] to a BigNumber
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - 
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.getBigNumber(ValueMetaBase.java:2205)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.setPreparedStatementValue(ValueMetaBase.java:5455)
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 -   ... 6 more
2019/04/13 18:48:37 - Insert / update.0 - Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. Copy&paste the whole error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for response.I just did, Could you please check

Comment: share the ktr file which you are using with some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Your PDI transformation is parsing the header row. It's trying to convert the literal string "questionRefnum" to a number. If you're reading from a file make sure you have the right number of header rows set.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting questionRefnum from a lookup table which shows itself as a bignumber when i check in output fields, not sure why its still trying to convert and throwing an error.